# How to load content script in chrome extension v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm migrating my v2 extension to v3. Now, the first thing that is not clear to me is how the content script is loaded into the page. I've implemented it as follows (background script):

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
    chrome.windows.create({
        // Just use the full URL if you need to open an external page
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("hello.html"),
         type: "panel", height: 200, width:200
    }, (win) => {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            const currTab = tabs[0];
            if (currTab) {
                chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                    target: {tabId: currTab.id},
                    files: ['/content.js'],
                }, () => {  });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I think that this example is my best attempt :)
So, when I run this code I get the following error in the console:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Hello, World!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": { "service_worker": "background.js" },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": { 
            "16": "icon16.png"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "bookmarks",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "optional_permissions": [],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["/content.js"],
            "matches": [],
            "extension_ids": [],
            "use_dynamic_url": true
        }
    ]
}
```

If I'm on the right path here, there must be something missing in my manifest. Any suggestions?

Comment: Content scripts can't be injected to an extension page. Simply load your script as `<script src="...">` in hello.html.

Comment: but I need to inject code in the active tab/page. In my v2 extension I do this with my content script because it has access the the page's document object

Comment: Currently you open a new active window and try to inject a content script into your own extension page which is active now. This is wrong and won't work. If you want to inject in the page which was active when the icon was clicked then remove query() and use `tab.id` for executeScript. The `onClicked` listener already gives you the `tab` object.

Comment: Yes, that seems to fix it, thnx

Answer (score 4):

try the following :-

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(insertScript)


async function insertScript() {
    tabId = await getTabId();
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tabId}
        files: ['/content.js']
    })
}


async function getTabId() {
    var tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
    return tabs[0].id;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting that your solution works, but the official chrome extension API reference [example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#injection-targets), don't.